# Trigger a pipeline from another repository to build at a specific time

Tags: triggers, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I have a Jenkins pipeline project that the script lives in a BitBucket repository 'A', when it builds, it clones Bitbucket repository 'B', compiles the app and deploys it. I want to trigger the pipeline to build at a specific time whenever there is a commit on the master branch of 'A'. The dev team works during regular working hours to merge changes for deployment, but we can only deploy on a weekend. I want to know the most efficient way to do this.
From what I've seen, the BitBucket trigger will only work to build that same project and it wont work to trigger on a scheduled time either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H 6 * * 6') // build every Saturday at 6:00 AM
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clone Repository') {
            steps {
                git 'https://bitbucket.org/username/repository-B.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Compile and Deploy') {
            steps {
                // compile and deploy the app here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your script will poll the same repository the pipeline is on to look for changes, not repository 'B'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generic webhook trigger plugin. This can be triggered from different repos and figure out, which on shall be built.